# Text area maxlength is not working when textarea is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my angular application [image: popup] I have an text area which is disabled, as shown in screenshot I have other inputs like a textbox and a listbox and few buttons the values selected or added from only those input's must be in my text area so my textarea is disabled, but as its been disabled the textarea maxlength is not working. I checked it by removing disable tag, the maxlength worked. but as per my requirement it must be disabled but now it is accepting more value than given maxlength.

Code:

```
<textarea maxlength="400" class="e-input formular-editor" placeholder="Formula" 
 [(ngModel)]="formula" formControlName="formula" style="width: 520px;" disabled></textarea>
```

Am I missing something or any other approach to achieve it when textarea is disabled?

Comment: What do you mean by it is accepting? Didn't you say it is disabled?

Comment: How it is possible to type if it is already disabled? it might not be disabled. something wrong

Comment: As shown in the screenshot, as per my requirement I have other like a textbox and a listbox the values selected or added from only those 2 will be in my text area so my textarea is disabled, but now as its been disabled the textarea maxlength is not working. I checked it by removing disable tag it worked then but as per my requirement it must be disabled.

Comment: you should use `readonly`

Comment: made it as readonly but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I checked you cannot type more than specified in `maxlength` attribute, even if it is disabled or not. But when adding data using JavaScript it exceeds the limit even if it is disabled or not. And I guess the reason is because `maxlength` restricts user but not developer who used JavaScript for modification. If that is your case you can truncate by slicing it.

```
var result=(textarea.value+value_to_add).split("").slice(0,maxlength).join("");
textarea.value=result;
```

Comment: This will either accept all or nothing. I'm very new to UI, is there any way which will accept value till my maxlength and truncate the rest, for example if i have maxlength as 15 and i give 20 characters, it should accept starting 15 characters and truncate the rest.

Comment: Yes you can, I have modified the answer with truncate feature